# Is it possible to destructure a public property of class in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, destructuring

I've got the following class in TypeScript.

```
class DBService {
  constructor(path: string) {
    this.initDatabase(path);
  }

  public db: lowDb.LowdbAsync<DatabaseSchema>;

  private async initDatabase(path: string) {
    const adapter = new FileAsync(path);
    this.db = await lowDb(adapter);

    await this.db
      .defaults({
        sites: [],
        events: [],
      })
      .write();
  }
}

export default DBService;
```

Now when I want to use it I create a new instance of the class like this.

```
const dbservice = new DBService(join(DB_DIR, 'db.json'));
```

But I'd like to directly access the public `db` property inside the class.

I've tried it with object destructuring like that.
But when doing so db is always undefined.

```
const { db } = new DBService(join(DB_DIR, 'db.json'));
console.log(db) // undefined
```

I have to always access the property with the class specified like that.

```
const dbservice = new DBService(join(DB_DIR, 'db.json'));
console.log(dbservice.db) // works
```

Is it not possible to destructure a public property of a class in JS/TS?

Comment: Try with 

const db = new DBService(join(DB_DIR, 'db.json')).db;

Comment: Does `console.log(dbservice.db)` really work? Because the actual problem appears to be that `this.db` is not yet set when you try to access it (because `initDatabase` is an async function). Instead of kicking off an async process in the constructor, why not have a static "builder" function which fetches/inits the DB and returns a new `DBService` instance? As it is now you actually don't know when the instance is ready to use.

Comment: @AndonMitev I've tried that too, but doesnt work either. Didn't want to include it because i thought its basically the same as destructuring.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah it works, it shows the structure of `db`. I'm just using `console.log` to test if it is undefined

Comment: See my updated comment. Are you sure you are doing `console.log(dbservice.db)` and not `console.log(dbservice)`? Either way, destructuring works as long as the property is set, but it's not set in your case, which is why Andon's suggestion doesn't work either. The problem is the asynchronous nature of `initDatabase`.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah `console.log(dbservice.db);` logs the whole structure of `db`. I get what you mean regarding the asynchrone nature of the init method but I'm wondering why that way works.